# Convolution of strictly positive density with some probability measure is positive?

Tags: probability-theory

If $f$ is a strictly positive density function on $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to Lebesgue measure and $P$ is some probability measure. Can we claim that
$$\int f(x-y)P(dy)>0?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is strictly positive on $\mathbb R$ then $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{y\mid g(y)>\frac1{n}\}$ so that - if $g$ is measurable: $$P(\{y\mid g(y)>\frac1n\})\to P(\mathbb R)=1$$ So for $n$ large enough we have $P(\{y\mid g(y)>\frac1n\})>0$ and consequently: $$\int g(y) P(dy)\geq\frac1nP\left(\{y\mid g(y)>\frac1n\}\right)>0$$

You can apply this on $g=g_x$ prescribed by $y\mapsto f(x-y)$.